# Implementing a slider with many items on one slide

Tags: javascript, css, slider, owl-carousel

How to implement a slider, in which individual elements will be lined up inside as in the screenshot.

I am using owl carousel.
I currently have such a structure:

```
<div class="sample-slider-wrapper border-bottom-block owlcarousel">
    <div class="samples-items-wrapper">
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Dv_BuildingBedPage::images/image3.png'); ?>" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Dv_BuildingBedPage::images/image3.png'); ?>" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Dv_BuildingBedPage::images/image3.png'); ?>" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Dv_BuildingBedPage::images/image3.png'); ?>" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Dv_BuildingBedPage::images/image3.png'); ?>" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the future, the elements will be taken from the database, but now, I want the elements on the 1st slide to not have 6 items on the mobile and 16 items on the desktop.

I currently have this configuration:

```
    require([
        'jquery',
        'owlcarousel'
    ], function () {
        'use strict';
        jQuery(".owlcarousel").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            nav : false,
            pagination : false,
            dots: true
        })
    });
```

Now if there are more than 6 elements, then they are transferred below and this breaks the idea of a two-level slider.

You need to somehow transfer them to the next slide. Tell me how to implement this.
The end result is this:

[image]